# Can't get a reset button to clear out a checkbox

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm using Vue.js v2 and I've defined a single-file component, RegionFacet.vue. It lists some regions that relate to polygons on a map (click a value, the corresponding polygon appears on the map).

Separately, I have a reset button. When that gets clicked, I call a method in RegionFacet to unselect any checkboxes displayed by RegionFacet. The model does get updated, however, the checkboxes remain checked. What am I missing?

```
<template>
  <div class="facet">
    <div class="">
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <a data-toggle="collapse"v-bind:href="'#facet-' + this.id"><h4 class="panel-title">Regions</h4></a>
          </div>
          <div v-bind:id="'facet-' + id" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <ul class="list-group">
              <li v-for="feature in content.features" class="list-group-item">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" class="rChecker"
                    v-on:click="selectRegion"
                    v-bind:value="feature.properties.name"
                    v-model="selected"
                    />
                  <span>{{feature.properties.name}}</span>
                </label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['content'],
    data: function() {
      return {
        id: -1,
        selected: []
      }
    },
    methods: {
      selectRegion: function(event) {
        console.log('click: ' + event.target.checked);

        if (event.target.checked) {
          this.selected.push(event.target.value);
        } else {
          var index = this.selected.indexOf(event.target.value);
          this.selected.splice(index, 1);
        }
        this.$emit('selection', event.target.value, event.target.checked);
      },
      reset: function() {
        this.selected.length = 0;
      }
    },
    created: function() {
      this.id = this._uid
    }
  }
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are directly setting the array length to be zero, which cannot be detected by Vue, as explained here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

Some more info: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

To overcome this, you may instead set the value of `this.selected` as follows:

```
reset: function() {
  this.selected = [];
}
```

Comment: That was it. Glad it was something simple -- thanks!